# Solve this integral using an appropiate substitution: $\iint_R x+y+1 dydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Solve this integral using an appropiate substitution: $$\iint_R x+y+1 dydx$$

Where $R$ is the area enclosed by the curves $y=1-x,y=2-x,y=1+x,y=-1+x$.

Which substitution would help here? I couldn't find one suitable, I solved this by separating the region in like 4 different ones, but clearly that's not the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the substitution $u = y+x, v=y-x$ (so $y = u+v, x= u-v$)

you need to also find the Jacobian of the transformation, which gives an extra factor of 2 in your transformed integral

so the integration becomes

$$\int_1^2 \int_{-1}^1 2(u+1)  dvdu$$

Comment: How could I realize that that substitution works?

Comment: but realizing how it works, do you mean how to discover it? or do you mean why is it mathematically valid? this type of using u and v for transformation is a common practice in multivariable calculus.

Comment: Oh I mean how to discover it! I'm having trouble, in general, finding good substitutions for double/triple integrals (even with this one which should've been really easy)... Do you have some general advice?

Comment: so as far as multivariable calculus problems of this kind, the region to integrate is almost always a parallelogram, which the two sets of parallel lines are given by {$y=m_1x+b_1$ , $y=m_1x+b_2$ } and {$y=m_2x+c_1$ , $y=m_2x+c_2$ }. In general you can just let $u = y-m_1x$ and $v = y-m_2x$ then the substitution should come out nicely

Comment: Thanks man :-). Last question: How do I figure out the boundaries after the substitution?

Comment: after doing the substitution, you would have $u=b_1$ and $u=b_2$ corresponding to the two parallel lines, those are your $du$ bounds. $v=c_1$ and $v=c_2$ corresponding to the other two parallel lines, those are your $dv$ bounds.

Answer (score 1):

@YoTengoUnLCD, I would draw the area $R$ and then look at how you have to rotate the axes of the coordinate system in order to have the sides of $R$ parallel to the axes. The new coordinates would be the substitution proposed in the answer of Ammon.